# getting MODE of generated numbers on Bash

Tags: bash

I need help getting the mode of randomly generated numbers in bash. i have no idea of where to start, any help?

i.e [1,2,3,3,4] the mode is  3.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

this works (replace the bit before the first pipe by whatever method you use to generate the numbers)

```
echo 1 2 3 3 4 | xargs printf "%s\n" | sort | uniq --count | sort | tail -n1 | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

If you want to know how it works, just try it adding one stage at a time.

```
echo 1 2 3 3 4 | xargs printf "%s\n"
echo 1 2 3 3 4 | xargs printf "%s\n" | sort
echo 1 2 3 3 4 | xargs printf "%s\n" | sort | uniq --count
....
```

if there is a tie, you will just get one of the two answers (the higher one I guess), and if one of there are more than 9 of anything, you will also probably get the wrong answer, but this is a start.

---

```
echo 1 2 3 3 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 |
  xargs -n1 echo | sort | uniq --count | sort -n | tail -n1 | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Thanks @mark-setchell. `-n` was needed on the latter sort to make it word with double digits

Also, I put `xargs -n1 echo` this time which I find easier to remember than `printf`

Comment: Replace `sort` with `sort -n`. Replace `xargs printf...` with `tr ' ' '\n'` and it will work better.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do it with a short bash function that reads `stdin` into an indexed array used to pipe the numbers to `sort` and then a loop that will fill a *frequency array* `arr` with the frequency of occurrence of each number while tracking the maximum number of occurrences. Then it simply outputs the mode for the set of number read, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

getmode () {
    mapfile input   ## stdin into array
    local -a arr    ## declare frequency array
    ## pipe sorted array to loop to capture frequency of each number
    printf "%s\n" ${input[@]} | sort -n |
    {
        mode=
        max=0
        while read -r n; do
            arr[$n]=$((${arr[n]}+1))        ## increment index at number
            ## check if arr[n] is most frequent
            [ "${arr[n]}" -gt "$max" ] &&
            {
                max="${arr[n]}"
                mode=$n
            }
        done
        echo "mode $mode"       ## output the mode
    }
}

echo $@ | getmode
```

(**note:** you will need to determine how to handle the mode if there are two (or more) values with an equal maximum occurrence - currently it will take the first of multiple equal maximums)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash findmode.sh 1 2 3 3 4
mode 3
```

or a longer unsorted set:

```
$ bash findmode.sh 1 8 3 1 5 2 7 5 3 9 5 1 6 5
mode 5
```